# Combobox is in a middle of the Grid

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The combobox in a row=0  is set to be in column 1 but is not in line with Entry label in row 1. I would expect it to be just after the text: "Password Length:" in line with Entry label on a row below.

```
long_t = Label(text='Password Length:')
long_t.grid(column=0,row=0)
choice_n = IntVar()
choice = ttk.Combobox(width=10)
w = [x for x in range(8,16)]
choice['values']= (w)
choice.grid(row=0, column=1)
choice.current()
choice.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callbackfunc)
password_text=Label(text='Password: ')
password_text.grid(row=1,column=0)
password_entry= Entry(width=20)
password_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)
generate = Button(text='Generate Password', command=pasw)
generate.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the sticky argument to line things up.

```
long_t = Label(text='Password Length:')
long_t.grid(column=0,row=0)
choice_n = IntVar()
choice = ttk.Combobox(width=10)
w = [x for x in range(8,16)]
choice['values']= (w)
choice.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
choice.current()
choice.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callbackfunc)
password_text=Label(text='Password: ')
password_text.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=W)
password_entry= Entry(width=20)
password_entry.grid(row=1,column=1, sticky=W)
generate = Button(text='Generate Password', command=pasw)
generate.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=W)
```